# Beveling compound curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Is there a way for beveling compound curves?

For example - Add icosphere -> Select all -> delete only faces -> convert mesh to curve -> bevel curve. Curve will be beveled but with a some kind of distort at some points. Is it possible to make it more consistent, except changing radius at every problem point?

Comment: Would using Add icosphere -> add wireframe modifier work better?

Comment: not really, icosphere just for example. If u have just intersected lines without faces, a lot of arbitrary lines, so it will be a way too long to make faces first

Comment: It's possible to get sort of beveling using [Skin modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html?highlight=skin%20modifier). However you still will be limited to intersections' style and stuff.

Comment: Yeah, skin modifier do the job but with a little distort at points  and it becomes imposible to change the profile shape. I thought there must be some option in curve properties to fix the problem. Anyway, I can't get why it deforms when beveling.